# Trying to use match with multiple criteria, to set a row depending on multiple criteria

Tags: vba

I am trying to set a row (pws) to be whichever row has 'ADJUSTMENT' in column A, 'India' in column B and 'Won' in column E.

The following works, matching just one criteria-

```
Dim pws As Variant

pws = Application.Match("India", PP.Columns("B"), 0)
```

But I can't find a way to add the other two criteria. Here is one attempt -

```
pws = Application.Match("India" & "ADJUSTMENT", PP.Columns("B") & PP.Columns("A"), 0)
```

I get

> runtime error '13' Type mismatch

Comment: `Match` is used for a single column, what are you trying to do to match 2 column at the same time?

Comment: Thanks, if I'm trying to define a row number based on multiple columns, what could I use instead of match? I have seen elsewhere - Evaluate("Match(""" & Va1 & -EVENTSqty & EVENTSdate & EVENTSttype & """, r_Events_ASIN & r_Events_ShippedQty & r_Events_Date & R_Events_Adj_Reason,0)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, your expected row can be achieved with `cell value` comparison using `If statement`, because it involve multiple column, therefore `match` function is not suitable here:

```
Sub findRow()

Dim lastrow As Long, irow As Long, resultRow As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For irow = 1 To lastrow
    With Sheet1
        If .Cells(irow, 1).Value = "Adjustment" And .Cells(irow, 2).Value = "India" _
            And .Cells(irow, 5).Value = "Won" Then
            resultRow = irow
            Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next

Debug.Print resultRow  'row is 10
End Sub
```

**Source data:** (Highlighted row is the first match row)

[image]